# Gatsby-Wordpress GraphQL does not update data when added from Wordpress

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, graphql, gatsby, wp-graphql

I have a website which I have developed using Gatsby. I have used WordPress for posting blogs for website and I'm fetching blogs using GraphQL. Everything is working fine, and I deployed the website on S3. After production deployment, when I published a new blog in WordPress, it is not being listed in the website using GraphQL. I had to re-deploy the code to make it working.

Is there any other way to load WordPress GraphQL data in production without rebuild and re-deploy?

Answer (score 0):

What you described is normal behavior. Gatsby is a static site generator so your data is "static" in terms of what is being built at the moment you run `gatsby build`. If something in the source changes, like publishing a post, you need to rebuild the site to make them available by GraphQL, hence Gatsby.

What you want to achieve is called webhook: an action that triggers another action. Like when publishing a post, trigger a new deploy to force the publishing of that post in a production environment.

You can follow this [article](https://medium.com/technogise/auto-build-gatsby-application-using-custom-webhook-on-wordpress-c3c5f70ca005) for a more approach that suits you.

If you are using Gatsby's v4, you can use the [new SSR (**S**erver-**S**ide **R**endering) brand feature](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/rendering-options/using-server-side-rendering) to serve data from the server or [DSG (**D**eferred **S**tatic Generation)](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/rendering-options/using-deferred-static-generation) for a combined approach, partially static, partially server-side served.